# ViewHolder views must not be attached when created. Inflator error

Tags: java, android, exception, android-recyclerview, runtime-error

This is my code of RecyclerView for Booking History and Im getting "java.lang.IllegalStateException: ViewHolder views must not be attached when created. Ensure that you are not passing 'true' to the attachToRoot parameter of LayoutInflater.inflate(..., boolean attachToRoot)" exception.

```
package com.example.bookinghistory;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<User> list;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<User> list) {
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item,parent,false);
        return new MyViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        User user = list.get(position);
        holder.Name.setText(user.getName());
        holder.Surname.setText(user.getSurname());
        holder.Date.setText(user.getDate());
        holder.Contact.setText(user.getContact());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView Name, Surname, Date, Contact;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            Name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvname);
            Surname = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvsurname);
            Date = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvdate);
            Contact = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvcontact);
        }
    }
}
```

Changed
View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item,parent);

to
View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item,parent,false);

But still it didnt work.

Comment: Everything looks alright. Try uninstalling the app and installing it again after u have made the change.LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item,parent);

to View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item,parent,false);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not set the context for your adapter that case you the error:

> LayoutInflater.from(context).......

**For Activity**

```
 MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(userList, this);
```

**For Fragment**

```
    MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(userList, requireContext());
```

But that's not the best practice

Here with **simple** and **shorter**

```
@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
       return new MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Declare:
lateinit var  context: Context

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        return ViewHolder(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false))
    }
```

Its Work for me!